# Что означает “%.7le ” в fprintf?

Tags: c++, c, printf

Что означает:

```
fprintf(fp, "%.7le ", data);
```

Я не понимаю, что "%.7le " означает.

Спасибо!

Comment: [`man fprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываете любую документацию по printf строке, например, эту https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf или https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

И понимаете, что e в конце обозначает "научный формат, в нижнем регистре", то есть, где то так `3.9265e+2`. В этом случае `.7` - это 7 цифр после запятой (по умолчанию их там 6). Меня смущает буковка `l` - она должна намекать на "длинный формат", но это просто double, то есть, можно просто убрать.

Answer (score 4):

Вывести значение типа `long double` c 7 знаками после запятой `3.1415926`

Спецификация в [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160)

Добавление от @avp:
`'L'` задает тип `long double` всюду, `'l'` - только в Windows.

Comment: Спецификаторы размера аргумента 'l' и 'L' для спецификаторов формата вывода плавающей точки (''e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'a', 'A') немного различны для \*nix-ов и винды. В винде 'l' и 'L' говорят, что аргумент типа *long double*, в \*nix только 'L' говорит, что аргумент *long double*, 'l' игнорируется, считается, что в этом случае аргумент имеет тип *double*. Т.е. только 'L' задает тип *long double* всюду. Поэтому  спецификатора 'l' лучше избегать

Comment: @avp Я на cppreference описания флагов уточнения типа не нашёл, на cplusplus по ссылке KoVadim только L, поэтому из MSDN взял информацию. А оно вон как... Дело именно в операционке (и рантайм библиотеках, видимо) или в компиляторах msvc vs gcc?

Comment: Я думаю, в рантайм библиотеках. Компилятор же (по крайней мере gcc) только проверяет форматы (ему известны printf/fprintf/...) и пишет warning

Comment: @avp Может, тогда ответом оформите? В цельном виде такая информация не помешает.

Comment: Лучше к себе в ответ добавьте (незачем почти одинаковые плодить -))

Comment: Хм, не поленился, открыл стандарт языка Си. Там чёрным по белому написано, что добавление модификатора ширины `l` к спецификатору `e` не должно оказывать никакого эффекта.  Т.е. `le` эквивалентно `e`, т.е. аргумент должен иметь тип `double`, n1570, 7.21.6.1/7: `The length modifiers and their meanings are: ... l ... or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier.`. Но у MS как обычно своё видение стандартов. Прискорбно.